# Best practice to restrict permissions on newly created folders?

Tags: vbscript, permissions, acl

I've got a script that the user runs which creates a group of sub-folders in the chosen directory. Obviously the newly created folders inherit the permissions of the parent directory. I need one folder in that newly created group to have a single different ACL to restrict one specific user from access.

Is there a way to automate this at the creation of the folder? Or is there a better way to deal with this?

So, to clarify: Imagine a folder path like the following: E:\datastore\marcstone bids\7501-8000\7501 some high school project\management documents

See how the second to last directory is a project name? There are literally hundreds of these, inside of which are the same 10 folders. I want all my users to have access to all those folders, except I need to restrict access to one folder for one user.

Unless I'm missing something, no matter how I set up the parent directory permissions (which will get inherited) I will still need to either remove or add a permission from/to that one folder after it's created. This just feels clumsy and complicated. Am I missing something? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to make that one user a member of a different group, and grant that group

- traverse permission on the parent folder (non-inheritable), and
- access on that one child folder (inheritable).

If you only want to deny access to one subfolder, it's even simpler: just add a deny ACE for that group on the respective folder.

Nothing clumsy or complicated about it.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't understand. Can you please explain that a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, but I think it makes a difference that I'm needing to deny access to the one deeply nested sub-folder.

Comment: @Mojoman317717 Perhaps I misread your question. My initial understanding was that you want a particular user to have access to just one subfolder, but none of the others. Did you mean the opposite: the user should have access to all but this one subfolder?

Comment: Yes, Ansgar. I want this one user to have access to all but the one deeply nested folder, and I can't seem to wrap my brain around the best method (or any method) without having to add the "deny permission" manually or with a script after the folder is created.